# Submitting multiple forms of the same object

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have a form that asks for basic information for a "guest" object, basically: name, phone, email. I also have a button that allows the user to "add more guests", which basically duplicates the original form using jQuery. When the user clicks the submit button, I want to have all of the guests that they have added in the page be submitted to the controller for creation. I'm struggling with figuring out the most appropriate way to handle a submit like this is.

1 - Should I be submitting multiple objects (of the same type) in seperate forms? I actually have the submit working right now using one form, and just making sure each guest attribute field name is unique (first_name_1, first_name_2, etc.). While this works, it feels very "hacky". I felt separating each guest into its own form was cleaner. Having everything in one form requires me to track how many attributes each guest can submit, and if for some reason they aren't submitted with the expected number of attributes, I'll have an error.

2 - Should I use jQuery + ajax for this submit? I don't know much about JSON, but would it make sense at all to use it for this?

I'm basically looking for a best practice for this situation. I think if I know the most appropriate way to handle it, I can probably find the syntax somewhere.

The application back end is rails. I can provide additional information if needed.

Thanks!

---

See below for the markup:

```
<div id=guests>
    <div id="guest1" class="guest">
        <form name="contact" class="form-horizontal bs-form" action=" " class="contact">
            <fieldset>
                <input required type="text" class="input-medium required" name="first_name_1" id="first_name_1" placeholder="First Name*" autocorrect="off" autocapitalization="on">
                <input required type="text" class="input-medium required" name="last_name_1" id="last_name_1" placeholder="Last Name*" autocorrect="off" autocapitalization="on">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium" name="phone_number" id="phone_number_1" placeholder="Phone Number" autocorrect="off">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium" name="email" id="email_1" placeholder="Email" autocorrect="off">
                <select class="host" name="host_1" id="host_1">
                    <option value="false" selected>Not table host</option>
                    <option value="true">Table host</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="add btn btn-info">Add Another Guest</a>

<div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-previous" id="addguestsubmit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrmce/GCBhL) that shows the markup and jquery doing the form creation/deletion. As I mentioned in my comments below, I'm not dealing with nested attributes, but an unknown number of forms with the same fields for the same model.

I'd be interested in knowing if my implementation of this is off too. I'm sure other people have accomplished this, but maybe in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have somewhere a GuestController, with two methods : edit and update, that you're running to change the guest object.

I faced the same pb on my app, and I solved it this way : the edit method can handle several forms, that are all processed by the same update action. I think it answer to the first part of youre question.

the edit action looks like this

```
def edit

 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 if  params[:customparam] == "edit_image"
  render 'edit_image'
 elsif  params[:customparam] == "edit_annonce"
  render 'edit_annonce'
 elsif  params[:customparam] == "edit_informations"
  render 'edit_informations'
 end

end
```

where 'edit_image' is a page with a form to change the profile pic.

The [:customparam] is something that I found so the controller action can recognize which button did the user press. You can add a custom param to a link_to, like this :

```
<%= link_to "Change image", edit_user_path(:user_id => current_user.id, customparam: "edit_image")"%>
```

So the controller recognize the button 'edit_image', and render the right form. All the forms are submitted to the update action, who change the user object.

I have no obvious thought about the second part, with un undefined amount of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a Railscasts episode [#196 Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), the tutorial is a simple question and answer app, which shows you how to add multiple **answers** to a **question** in the *question* form. Similar of you want to save multiple guests at the same time. Have a look and see if it helps. There's also a [part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

**EDIT:**

Gem [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

Comment: I admittedly haven't watched the rails cast yet, but is this method dependent on knowing how many forms will be presented to the user? In my case, the user can decide how many they will submit, I don't have anything that allows me to determine how many guests a single person can have.

Comment: If you check out part 2, he shows how you can add many answers instead of a fixed number. Theres also a gem called nested_form, check it out which you could use. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Another gem similar to nested_form is [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

Comment: I watched the rails casts and checked out both gems. I might be missing it, but I don't know if they apply to my situation. I'm not dealing with nested attributes. All of the forms being submitted will be of the same model type (guests) and have the same attributes. If it helps, here's a fiddle of my markup + jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/jrmce/GCBhL/